# Typescript + Angular : variable changing context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-material

since I transitioned from JavaScript to TypeScript (Version 2.1.5), the following code that filters the date selection is not working anymore. And I think I know why, but I haven't found a good fix at this moment.

Here are my two date-pickers : From and To :

```
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="label label-letter-spacing">From </label>
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datepickerFrom'>
                                    <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.dateFrom"></md-datepicker>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="label label-letter-spacing">To </label>
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datepickerTo'>
                                    <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.dateTo" md-date-filter="vm.onlyGreaterThanFromDate" ></md-datepicker>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

In the Controller.ts I have :

```
        dateTo: Date;
        dateFrom: Date;

        onlyGreaterThanFromDate(date) {
           if (this.dateFrom != undefined )
               return (date.getTime() > this.dateFrom.getTime());
        };
```

While debugging in browser (chrome), I noticed that when this method is executed, the context has changed and **this** represents no more my Controller, but  the CalendarCtrl , and so, the **this.dateFrom** is undefined .

I tried some tweaks as setting dateFrom property in  static or private, but doesn't work neither.

I'm still searching and i'm looking forward to reading your comments/ideas on this.  :)  Thank you

Comment: Can you show the entire ts code file please? It sounds like a scoping issue from what you describe about the this variable changing context

Comment: In Typescript you can use arrow function to preserve the context. Something like: `onlyGreaterThanFromDate = (date) => {
           if (this.dateFrom != undefined )
               return (date.getTime() > this.dateFrom.getTime());
        };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much **Hung Cao** for your answer. That was the right code and I learned a useful feature in TypeScript :)

So I'm re-posting the solution :

> In Typescript you can use arrow function to preserve the context.
>   Something like: onlyGreaterThanFromDate = (date) => { if
>   (this.dateFrom != undefined ) return (date.getTime() >
>   this.dateFrom.getTime()); };